# Swift Codable expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any>but found a string/data instead

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

I have been working with the `Codable` protocol

Here is my `JSON` file :

```
    {  
   "Adress":[  

   ],
   "Object":[  
      {  
         "next-date":"2017-10-30T11:00:00Z",
         "text-sample":"Some text",
         "image-path":[  
            "photo1.png",
            "photo2.png"
         ],
         "email":"john.doe@test.com",
         "id":"27"
      },
      {  
         "next-date":"2017-10-30T09:00:00Z",
         "text-sample":"Test Test",
         "image-path":[  
            "image1.png"
         ],
         "email":"name.lastename@doe.com",
         "id":"28"
      }
   ]
}
```

I only have to focus on the Object array, and the "image-path" array can contain 0, 1, or 2 strings.

**So here is my implementation:**

```
struct Result: Codable {
    let Object: [MyObject]
}

struct MyObject: Codable {

    let date: String
    let text: String
    let image: [String]
    let email: String
    let id: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date = "next-date"
        case text = "text-sample"
        case image = "image-path"
        case email = "email"
        case id = "id"
    }

    init() {
        self.date = ""
        self.text = ""
        self.image = []
        self.email = ""
        self.id = ""
    }
}
```

I call it from my service class after requesting and getting the JSON data this way:

```
if let data = response.data {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let result = try! decoder.decode(Result, from: data)
                dump(result.Object)
            }
```

Everything is working except the `[String]` for the `image` property

But it can't compile, or I get an "Expected to decode..." error.

How should I handle the nil/no data scenario?

Comment: Basically the code (the first implementation) is supposed to work, but the JSON is not valid. You don't need the `init` method at all if you are always using the decoder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have made a small change in your `MyObject struct`, i.e.,

**1.** Marked all `properties` as `optionals`

**2.** Removed `init()` (I don't think there is any requirement of `init()` here.)

**3.** Use `Result.self` instead of `Result` in `decoder.decode(...)` method

```
struct MyObject: Codable
{
    let date: String?
    let text: String?
    let image: [String]?
    let email: String?
    let id: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case date = "next-date"
        case text = "text-sample"
        case image = "image-path"
        case email = "email"
        case id = "id"
    }
}
```

To test the above, I have used the below code and it is working fine.

```
    let jsonString = """
        {"Adress": [],
        "Object": [{"next-date": "2017-10-30T11:00:00Z",
        "text-sample": "Some text",
        "image-path": ["photo1.png", "photo2.png"],
        "email": "john.doe@test.com",
        "id": "27"},
      {"next-date": "2017-10-30T09:00:00Z",
       "text-sample": "Test Test",
       "image-path": ["image1.png"],
       "email": "name.lastename@doe.com",
       "id": "28"}
       ]
        }
    """
    if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
    {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let result = try? decoder.decode(Result.self, from: data) //Use Result.self here
        print(result)
    }
```

This is the **result** value that I am getting:

[image]

Comment: With same sample I can't make it work. "debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.65.2/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 181"

Comment: Did you use Result.self?

Comment: Nevermind. Never trust backend, I had a typo in the json from production. My code was working since the beginning... Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Sure..Happy coding..:)

Comment: ```Marked all properties as optionals``` — why would you do that?

Comment: Because it is not confirmed that you will get all the key-value pairs from API. Instead of initialising them with empty string/array, its better they are nil. That is the reason I used optional for them.

Comment: @PGDev absolutely correct. Never trust a backend :-)